# How I can use GWT's TypeOracle?

Tags: gwt, module

is it possible to use com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.TypeOracle within my code? I need this class to get an array of all subtypes of a specified class at runtime. Which module I have to inherit?

I get two errors during GWT compile:

[ERROR] Line 74: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.TypeOracle; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Line 75: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType; did you forget to inherit a required module?

What could be wrong?

Thank you

Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use it at runtime.

`TypeOracle` is used to infer type infos about classes used at compile-time. GWT generators often use `TypeOracle` as a source of such informations.

You may want to change your perspective and build a generator that infer all subtypes of a given annotated class, or use a library that allow you to use client-side reflection (never used, but they exists and, in the end they simply use the same idea: generators/deferred binding mechanism).

Comment: I'll try to write a generator, which creates a class, which stores the information in a static List. So I could access it on runtime. I hope it will work...